# Extracting NDVI for large extensions using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi

I'm trying to calculate NDVI in ArcGIS for Desktop using MODIS to entire neotropical region but I can't find MODIS values for all neotropical.

Instead, I foud only for small regions.

Does someone know how to extract NDVI for large extensions at the same time?

Comment: Is this a data download question or data processing, can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

There is no MODIS data covering the entire neotropics (that´s quite a large area), but you can download several NDVI tiles from the MODIS data archive. I suggest you use the reverb.echo website (EOSDIS):

http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/

There you can draw either a polygon around the area you want or even upload a shapefile covering your desired extent. Then search for the MODIS NDVI product of your choice, set the time span and then look what´s there. I guess a lot of tiles. You will then have to modify all of them using the MRT tool (= MODIS reprojection tool). This allows you to preproject and merge all images in one folder into a coordinate system e.g. UTM or geographic coordinate system.

Comment: Thak you Jens! The information was very helpful